# Tikz and drawing siblings on one line tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I'm using tikz to create a graph of a network. Currently, I'm having difficulties with one tree, where I would like to set it up like the picture below to save space.

[image]

1 is the parent and connects to a different part of the diagram. When I make children of one, I create a straight line (and have a straight line going through them). Like this picture

[image]

I've read some of the tikz style and documentation and couldn't find the best way of doing this.

edit 1:I need to add more. Here is what I have.

edit 2: here is the whole code. My apologies my first time on tex.stackexchange

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,landscape,border shrink=5mm]
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
     \node {1} [rectangle,draw, sibling distance = 40mm]
        child{node[rectangle,draw] {1a}
                        child[grow =
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.east)}] {node [rectangle,draw,yshift = -20.5mm]{2}}
                        child[grow =
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.east)}]  {node [rectangle, draw, yshift =-30.5mm]{3}}
                        child[grow =
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.east)}]  {node [rectangle, draw,yshift = -40.5mm] {4}}
                        child[grow =
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -| (\tikzchildnode.east)}]  {node [rectangle, draw,yshift = -50.5mm] {5}}
                        child[grow =
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -| (\tikzchildnode.east)}]  {node [rectangle, draw,yshift = -60.5mm] {6}}
                        child[grow =
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -| (\tikzchildnode.east)}]  {node [rectangle, draw,yshift = -70.5mm] {7}}}
        child{node[rectangle, draw] {1b}}
        child{node[rectangle, draw] {2b}}
        child{node[rectangle, draw] {3b}}
        child{node[rectangle, draw] {4b}}
        child{node[rectangle, draw] {5b}};

  \end{tikzpicture}




\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello and [welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: See example in TeXample.net: http://www.texample.net/media/tikz/examples/PDF/family-tpdfree.

Comment: Please always post a complete minimal example i.e. make your code compilable, please, so we can reproduce the issue!

Comment: Thanks for completing your code. Don't you get compilation errors from that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

[image: circular folders ??!!]

This was drawn using `forest`, which is a specialist drawing package for trees, based on TikZ.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    draw,
    circle,
    grow=-180,
    edge={thick},
    thick,
    edge path'={%
      (!u.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)
    }
  },
  for root={
    parent anchor=south,
    delay={%
      prepend={[, phantom, calign with current]}
    }
  }
  [1,
    [2]
    [3]
    [4]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: hey, thanks. I guess I was using the wrong package. I also edited my question.

Comment: Not necessarily. I just like `forest` because it is particularly powerful and flexible. But you can surely do this with TikZ's own `trees` or another of the tree-drawing packages, if you prefer. If the nodes were to the right, rather than the left, of the root you could probably use `dirtree` if you wished.